# How can I compile Raylib to WASM in Golang?

Tags: go, webassembly, raylib

I'm trying to compile Raylib to WASM in Golang, but when I run the command `env GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build .` Go can't seem to compile rcamera, and it gives me the following error message

```
# github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:196:27: undefined: GetMouseDelta
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:220:56: undefined: GetFrameTime
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:226:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:229:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:232:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:235:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:238:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:241:6: undefined: IsKeyDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:246:8: undefined: IsGamepadAvailable
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:248:29: undefined: IsMouseButtonDown
../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go/raylib@v0.0.0-20231123174446-48309e2407b7/rcamera.go:248:29: too many errors
```

I have no clue why the library won't compile, and I can't find anything online. It's also possible it can't compile the entire Raylib library and go just doesn't get that far because there's to many error messages, but I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible at the moment.
Take a look at issues #69 and #119 on the raylib-go repository